# Return a data frame from apply, even though the results are of different length

Tags: r, apply, plyr, zoo

I really feel that the answer to this question should be somewhere on the web, but I just can't find it. Please redirect me if you find a thread/site explaining it.

My problem: I want to apply a function to each row in a data frame and get a data frame back, but apply gives me a list since the lengths of my results are varying.

My example: I need to interpolate NAs rowwise in a data frame. na.approx in zoo can easily interpolate column-wise, however I want to do it row-wise.

```
> df <- data.frame(C1=c(1,2,NA),C2=c(2,NA,5),C3=c(NA,7,8))

> na.approx(df)
C1  C2 C3
[1,]  1 2.0 NA
[2,]  2 3.5  7
[3,] NA 5.0  8
```

I want the 3.5 in the middle to be 4.5: the average of 2 and 7, not 2 and 5. So I can do this:

```
> t(na.approx(t(df)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  2.0   NA
[2,]    2  4.5    7
[3,]   NA  5.0    8
```

And that's OK, but in order to learn apply and plyr I would like to acheive the same result with these. However the result is not what I want:

```
> apply(df,1,function(x){na.approx(x)})
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2.0 4.5 7.0

[[3]]
[1] 5 8
```

It gives me a list.. if I have a data.frame without NAs in the first and last rows, then it works fine:

```
> df.2 <- data.frame(C1=c(1,2,3),C2=c(2,NA,5),C3=c(4,7,8))
> apply(df.2,1,function(x){na.approx(x)})
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  2.0    3
[2,]    2  4.5    5
[3,]    4  7.0    8
```

This is expected, I assume, and what the ?apply documentation says:
"If the calls to FUN return vectors of different lengths, apply returns a list of length prod(dim(X)[MARGIN]) with dim set to MARGIN if this has length greater than one."

But if I really want a data frame, how should I do? I would like to learn plyr, so but aaply does not work either (for the same reason, I assume)

```
> aaply(df,1,function(x){na.approx(x)})
Error: Results must have the same dimensions.
```

Thank you.

Alfred

Answer (score 1):

Use **na.rm=FALSE.** or **na.rm=F**

```
apply(df,1,function(x){na.approx(x, na.rm=FALSE)})
```

Please refer the [zoo package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf#na.approx)  for more details

Comment: which can be written: `apply(df, 1, na.approx, na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks Nishu Tayal and @G. Grothendieck! Can you also tell me why plyr with $ aaply(df,1,.fun=function(x){na.approx(x, na.rm=FALSE)}) $ doesn't produce the same result? Rather it gives me an a 4D array (I think)?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `na.rm=FALSE`:

```
> apply(df,1,function(x){na.approx(x,na.rm = F)})
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  2.0   NA
[2,]    2  4.5    5
[3,]   NA  7.0    8
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! Please also see my question to the above answer by Nishu Tayal regarding the use of aaply from the Plyr package rather than apply.